# Вид / Наклонение

Tags: наклонение

*Публикация была направлена против него.*

Kак я понимаю, это русский пассив в изъявительном наклонении. В виде ведь все равно существуют различия наклонения, не правда ли? Можно ведь сказать *Публикация была бы / могла бы быть направлена против него* (страдательный вид/сослагательное наклонение)? Или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: Нет, не ошибаетесь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В приведенном выше предложении действительно наблюдается изъявительное наклонение: действие имело место быть. И, как вы уже сказали, это пассив: публикацию именно направили, а не она сама совершила действие.